# Convertir EditText con letras a double

Tags: android

Tengo un EditText que tiene numeros y letras (moneda - 12.00 €) y quiero pasarlo a double (12.00) para poder trabajar con el como numero. ¿Como se pueed hacer?. Lo he intentado asi pero no me funciona:

```
  double modcuota =  Double.parseDouble(cuota.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: Ante de convertir a double, tienes que quitar los caracteres que no sean numéricos y el punto decimal. ¿Es realmente necesario que tecleen el símbolo de la moneda? Si solo trabajas en euros, podrías suponer que siempre teclean euros y no tendrías que teclear el símbolo del euro.

Answer (score 0):

En Java tienes el método replaceAll() que recibe por parámetro dos strings, el primero es un regex y el segundo el valor final del carácter que lo cumple.  De esta manera, para quedarte sólo con el valor double, he picado el siguiente código que funcionará para tu caso:

```
 private static Double convert(String text) {
    final String EMPTY_SPACE = "";
    final String DOUBLE_REGEX = "[^0-9.]+";
    String extractValue = text.replaceAll(DOUBLE_REGEX, EMPTY_SPACE);

    return Double.valueOf(extractValue);
}
```

Comment: OK pero que te devuelve replaceALL

Comment: replaceAll devuelve un String y se puede convertir a double: Double.valueOf(tuString).  Acabo de editarlo para que se ajuste al 100% ;)